# Structure theory of Schubert varieties (extend results from semisimple groups to reductive)

Tags: reductive-groups, buildings, schubert-varieties

The lecture notes [Borel–Weil–Bott theorem and geometry of Schubert varieties](https://kumar.math.unc.edu/notes/kumar_notes_03.pdf) by Shrawan Kumar present a concise summary of major results on cohomology of flag varieties $G/B$ for $G$ **semisimple**, simply-connected, complex algebraic group, $B$ Borel.

At the first page is remarked that the presented results can be fairly straight forward extended to a connected *reductive* group.

Do somebody know a recomendable treatise written in similar "concise overview style" as the linked survey, discussing more concretely the extension to reductive case in similar manner laying focus on where and how the discussed constructions in the linked paper have to be modified to extend from semisimple to reductive case?

Ie, which constructions presented in the linked paper literally "go through" and which require substantial modifications (and how these modifications are caried out)? (E.g., semisimple rank issues etc….)

(If the number of neccessary modifications of the discussed constructions to pass from semisimple to reductive case is "countable by hand", so one don't have to go too far to point them out, could somebody summarize roughly, what changes?)

Comment: If $G$ is reductive, $[G,G]$ is semisimple. The flag and Schubert varieties for them are identical. I vote to close.

Comment: Additionally to @BugsBunny's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1174664_453967), the reason the flag varieties are identical is that $G$ is the almost-direct product of $[G, G]$ with the centre of $G$, and $B$ is the almost-direct product of $[G, G] \cap B$ with the centre of $G$.

Comment: @LSpice: just to clarify, so this has as consequence that the "conbinatorical/simplicial data" induced by standard parabolics of $G$ and $[G,G]$ are isomorphic, the flag vars $G/P$ and $G'/P'$ are isomorphic if we set the notation $A':=A \cap [G,G]$, right? Two points are still not clear: What can one say about relations of Weyl groups (...in order to compare their Tits systems) and (integral) weight groups (...to compare irreps via highest weight thm) of $G$ and $[G,G]$? How "close" are they to each other?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1174704), I'm not sure what $A$ is.  The Weyl groups agree, because $N_G(S)$ equals $N_{[G, G]}(S \cap [G, G])\cdot Z(G)$ and $C_G(S)$ equals $C_{[G, G]}(S \cap [G, G])\cdot Z(G)$ for a maximal split torus $S$ (maybe that's your $A$?).  A weight is a character that pairs integrally with all coroots, and the coroots are the same for $G$ and for $[G, G]$ (the roots are obviously the same, and at least one construction of a coroot of $G$ shows that it is valued in $[G, G]$).  There can be more weights for $G$ than for $[G, G]$ (consider $G$ a torus!).

Comment: I think $A$ was meant as a placeholder for any letter, to define $P'$, $G'$, $B'$, etc. all at once

Comment: @MaxHorn, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1174734_453967), makes sense, thanks!  (I got confused because $A$ is sometimes used to denote a maximal split torus, and sometimes a maximal split, *central* torus, so I thought it had meaning but wasn't sure what.)

Comment: @LSpice: sorry for causing confusion, by notation $A'$ I meant exactly what Max Horn wrote. One point I still not understand: as you said obviously it could happen that $G$ has more weights than $ [G,G]$. In the linked paper several constructions involve constructions using weights, so the question is how these  extend from semisimple to reductive case in spirit of this "philosophy" that by passing from reductive $G$ to semisimple $[G,G]$ nearly "no  representation theoretic information get lost"? A guess: Does it has something to do with so called notion of "semisimple rank"? Namely, when

Comment: when one deals with reductive $G$ , one considers not weights with respect to max torus $T_G$ of $G$, but  only with weights of "semisimple torus" obtained as quotient $T_G/R((G)^{\circ}$? Otherwise  I don't know in which sense those constructions in the paper involving weights performed with semisimple group extend to redctive case.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1174750), an irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G$ has a central character.  That is, there is some character $\chi_\pi$ of $Z(G)$ such that the restriction of $\pi$ to $Z(G)$ is multiplication by the scalar $\chi_\pi$.  The study of irreducible representations of $G$ is thus just the study of pairs (irreducible representation $\pi'$ of $[G, G]$, character $\chi$ of $Z(G)$), where the restriction of $\pi'$ to $[G, G] \cap Z(G)$ is multiplication by $\chi$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1174751_453967), actually, one considers not $T_G/{\operatorname R(G)}$ (I am not sure of what you are taking the identity component), but $T_G \cap [G, G]$.  The projection map of this latter to $T_G/{\operatorname R(G)}$ is an isogeny.

Comment: (And I just noticed that I've been speaking of the centre $Z(G)$ all along when I meant the *connected* centre, which is the torus $\operatorname R(G)$.)

Comment: @LSpice: right, taking the identity component of $R(G)$ wasn't neccessary; I just missed to note that for $G$ reductive, $R(G)$ is alrealy a torus, *not* only after taking the identity component. Also, so is this isogeny between $T_G/R(G)$ and  $T_G \cap [G,G]$ then exactly the core reason why the so called "semi-simple rank" (= rank of  $T_G$ minus rank of $R(G)$ ) 
becomes "interesting", even though one primary not works directly with $T_G /R(G)$? Or in other words, are there any "other" reasons why this rather "artificially constructed" semi- simple rank becomes inportant in the theory?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1174755_453967), exactly. The semisimple rank of $G$ is the rank of its semisimplification $[G, G]$.

Comment: @LSpice: ...and the reason that the roots of reductive $G$ and semisimple $[G,G]$ coincide, follows precisely from the observation that for all roots $\chi$ of $G$ (ie those characters $\chi$ such that there exist nonzero eigenspace $\mathfrak{g}_{\chi} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ in the root decomp) holds $\chi(R(G))=1$, right? In that case the rank of the roots in $G$ and $[G,G]$ coinside and is exactly the semi-simple rank from before, is this conclusion correct?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1175205_453967)$\newcommand\o{\operatorname}$, I'm not sure what "the rank of the roots" means.  Restriction to $S \cap [G, G]$ provides a bijection of root systems because the map $\o{Lie}([G, G])/{\o{Lie}(\o C_{[G, G]}(S \cap [G, G])} \to \o{Lie}(G)/{\o{Lie}(\o C_G(S))}$ is an $S$-equivariant isomorphism of vector spaces, and, as you say, $\operatorname R(G)$ acts trivially on $\o{Lie}(G)$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1175205_453967), ah, maybe by "the rank of the roots" you mean "the rank of the root system", i.e., the size of a system of simple roots.  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes exacty, I meant there "the rank of the root system". But about the statement that the restriction $S \cap[G,G]$ provides a bijection of root systems: Firstly, $\text{Lie}([G, G])/{\text{Lie}( C_{[G, G]}(S \cap [G, G])} \to \text{Lie}(G)/{\text{Lie}(C_G(S))}$ is an $S$-equiv iso, essentially because of $ C_G(S)=  C_{[G,G]}(S \cap [G,G]) \cdot Z(G)$. Also, we know that that $R(G)$ acts trivial on $\text{Lie}(G)$. But why this then implies the bijection between the root systems?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453967/structure-theory-of-schubert-varieties-extend-results-from-semisimple-groups-to#comment1175488_453967), because the roots are precisely the weights on the indicated quotient.

Comment: @LSpice: but then I not understand where in your argumentation chain you exploit the fact that $R(G)$ acts trivially on $\text{Lie}(G)$? Indeed, so far I understand the motivation to consider the quotient $\text{Lie}(G)/{\text{Lie}(C_G(S))}$ (and same story with left one), lies - so far I understand it  correctly -  to assure that it's weights are precisely the roots of $G$, namely quoting out $\text{Lie}(C_G(S))$ in weight decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in X_*(S)} \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}$ "kills" $\mathfrak{g}_0$, exactly the guy not coming from a root.

Comment: But as remarked, in this argument I nowhere see where in this argumentation chain the triviality of the $R(G)$-action on $\text{Lie}(G)$ is going to be explicitly exploited.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1175699), one need never refer to $\newcommand\o{\operatorname}\o R(G)$ to compute roots of $S$ on $G$, or of $S \cap G'$ on $G'$ ($G' \mathrel{:=} [G, G]$), alone. But the two sets of roots cannot literally match, since they're functions on different tori.  However, restriction from $S$ to $S \cap G'$ provides a bijection: every root of $S \cap G'$ on $\o{Lie}(G')$ is trivial on $\operatorname R(G) \cap G'$, and then we just extend roots trivially across $\operatorname R(G)$ to find the inverse map to restriction.